# How to short this code, i'm doing same for each and declare variable

Tags: php

I think my code is ugly for such thing, i'm doing twice foreach.

```
$peoples;
$container = [];

foreach( $this->media_model->people as $person )
{
    $people = Person::whereHas('jobs', function( Builder $query ){
        $query->where('job_name', '=', 'Artist');
    })->get();

    $peoples = $people;
}
```

$peoples return json

```
[
    {
        "person_id": 1,
        "first_name": "Suzuki",
        "last_name": "Amanda"
    },
    {
        "person_id": 3,
        "first_name": "Stephen",
        "last_name": null
    }
]
```

i need to do something again with the data to join first name and last name

```
foreach( $peoples as $person )
{
    array_push($container, $person->first_name.' '.$person->last_name);
}

return $container;
```

In the end the json data will be

```
[
    "Suzuki Amanda",
    "Stephen "
]
```

Comment: Which framework you are using?

Comment: Looks like Laravel

Comment: @ServingQuarantineperiod Laravel, I already present what the output each foreach json .

Comment: @brombeer yes, laravel. but i think this php case to short code.

Comment: Create an accessor maybe? [Defining An Accessor](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor)

Comment: I think you need to use `join` so that In one go query will give you all person and there corresponding job or what ever it is.  Also `foreach( $this->media_model->people as $person )` seems useless as you didn't use `$person` data inside query

Comment: @ServingQuarantineperiod How to do that? Cause 3 model use 2 junction table. ex. `person, job, media` model. it connect each other with `media_people, person_jobs` table. Cause it connect, first i retrieve what people in a media. after that i filter by job. then, join `first_name` and `last_name`.